# Expire an unresponsive command line call

Tags: linux

I want to check a URL's response by command line.  I've seen some other questions on this, offering solutions such as `wget` and `curl -Is url`.  but none seem to work when the URL in question is valid but it's ultimate server is down or otherwise unresponsive.  The curl call just waits, which prevents any programatic response.  What would be the best way to time the call out after a few seconds and consider it a negative result?

Comment: `wget --help | grep timeout` and `curl --help | grep timeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to curl or wget, but you can use the [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) utility from GNU coreutils to cause any program whatsoever to run only for a limited amount of time. I've used it, for instance, to scrape Twitter for 5 minutes while I go get some coffee.

Answer (score 2):

According to curl's man-page you have two options to help you with that.

```
--connect-timeout 
-m,  --max-time
```

The first handles the connection phase, the second the actual request *after* connect.  Have a play.